# Android -- Can RecyclerViews not smooth scroll right?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, smoothing

I have two arrow buttons for scrolling left and right 3 items (or to the beginning or end of the list, respectively).  Scrolling left -- where the target position is less than the current position -- only works.  When scrolling right, `smoothScrollToPosition()` is not even invoked.  Has anyone ran into this? Do I have to reverse the list somehow?

**My extension of LinearLayoutManager**:

```
public class SmoothScrollLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager {

private static final float MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH =  50f;
private Context context;

public SmoothScrollLayoutManager(Context context, int orientation, boolean reverseLayout) {
    super(context, orientation, reverseLayout);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void smoothScrollToPosition(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.State state, final int position) {

    LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(context) {

        @Override
        public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
            return SmoothScrollLayoutManager.this.computeScrollVectorForPosition(targetPosition);
        }

        @Override
        protected float calculateSpeedPerPixel(DisplayMetrics displayMetrics) {
            return MILLISECONDS_PER_INCH / displayMetrics.densityDpi;
        }


    };

    smoothScroller.setTargetPosition(position);
    startSmoothScroll(smoothScroller);
  }
}
```

**computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition)** from LinearLayoutManager

```
   public PointF computeScrollVectorForPosition(int targetPosition) {
    if (getChildCount() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    final int firstChildPos = getPosition(getChildAt(0));
    final int direction = targetPosition < firstChildPos != mShouldReverseLayout ? -1 : 1;
    if (mOrientation == HORIZONTAL) {
        return new PointF(direction, 0);
    } else {
        return new PointF(0, direction);
    }
}
```

I scroll by calling `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);`

Any help is much appreciated. I've been stuck on this for much of the day.

Comment: Can you change the context of  `LinearSmoothScroller` to `recyclerView.getContext()` like this `LinearSmoothScroller smoothScroller = new LinearSmoothScroller(recyclerView.getContext()) {` and test it again.

Comment: Didn't change anything. :/

Comment: I believe I'm experiencing the same issue/behavior. Did you happen to figure this out? Would appreciate an update here if you have.